# Google Sitemap Problem

Tags: sitemap

I submitted a sitemap to Google and I got this error.

Incorrect namespace
Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace. Expected: http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1 Found: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1

I thought that sitemaps.org was okay. I took it from Google's example:

[Google's sitemap example](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183668)

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

```
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1
```

with

```
http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1
```

since that seem to be problem?

If you have and that didn't help, can you post your sitemap here? Include just a few url tags.

Update: This page may be of use: http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php. It's where I started when I wrote my first sitemap.

Another thought: In case you don't link directly to images or videos but only to html pages or php pages, you probably can remove

```
xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
```

and

```
xmlns:video="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1
```

I'm not using that code in my sitemap, and it works as it should.

Comment: Hi Matsolof, Thank you for the message. Actually, I did make the change that you outlined above. I changed sitemaps.org to google.com and it worked. It's strange that Google's own example used sitemaps.org. Thank you for you kind help.

Comment: It's not the first error I've encountered at google.com. I have a feeling that Google spend too much time growing and too little time improving.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello,**
Actually the solution was **replacing this:**

`<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/ https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd"
    xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`

**With this:**

`<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">`

And it works as expected and [Google sitemap](https://search.google.com/search-console/sitemaps) can be able to read the file.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

XML namespaces are used for providing uniquely named elements and attributes in an XML document.

Name conflicts in XML can easily be avoided using a name prefix.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/"> <html> <body>   <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>   </table> </body> </html> </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```