# Is there anything wrong with this sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, sitemap

I am having trouble with google sitemaps as follow:

Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the namespace.

Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't declare the expected namespace: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
Parent tag: urlset
Tag: url

The sitemap as discussed: http://kampar4rent.com/sitemap/

Any ideas what may be wrong?

**Additional Note:**

I have tested validation of the xml with this tool and no errors were found:

http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Somewhere with similar issue: [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794940/google-sitemap-problem)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075782/how-do-you-remove-xmlns-from-elements-when-generating-xml-with-linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the error:

> Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't declare the expected
>   namespace: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 Parent tag:
>   urlset Tag: url

Well, it says what you're supposed to do: remove xmls from the `url` tag